# Count how many cells contain this string with lookup value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, countif

I have a large table of IDs and file quality from files that pertain to that ID. There are multiple files that constitute a data point (imaging data, volumetric in manner) so there are multiple rows per ID. A sample table similar in manner is posted below.

[image]

The goal is to create a function that will count how many "good" and "bad" values are per lookup subject in the SubjID column. There are ranges I want to follow, where if >50% of the `G_R_B` values for that `SubjID` are `good`, than `G_R_B` = `G`, 50% is `good` = `R`, and x<50% is `good` = `B`.

I will then sort and get unique value per subject ID.

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this? I tried using `VLOOKUP` and `COUNTIF` and found ways to do it [when all duplicate IDs are stripped](https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/count/count-numbers-by-range-with-countifs), but I am struggling to take into account when duplicate IDs occur.

*EDIT*: SAMPLE TABLE TO SEE WHAT TO DO IF RANGES ARE INVOLVED (see comment)

[image]

Comment: Probably something along the lines of `=LET(x,COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,A:A,"good")/COUNTIF(B:B,B2),IF(x>0,5,"G",IF(x<0,5,"B","B")))` if you can use `LET()`.

Comment: @JvdV I unfortunately do not have `LET()`. I am currently trying to combine `VLOOKUP` and `COUNTIFS`

Comment: Then you may have to use the same logic multiple times as per answer below. The problem here with `VLOOKUP()` would be the exact match for 50% whilst the other options are a range between the outer bounds of 0 and 100 upto or from 50%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't use latest Excel formulas, you can use:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,"good",$B$2:$B$7,B2)/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,B2)>0.5,"G",IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,"good",$B$2:$B$7,B2)/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,B2)<0.5,"B","R"))
```

Result:

[image]

`COUNTIF` used to find how many times value in `B2` appears in `B` column.

`COUNTIFS` used to find how many times value in `B2` appears in `B` column, with criteria "good" in column `A`

EDIT:

Updated formula according to your comment and edit:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$21,"good",$B$2:$B$21,B2)/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$21,B2)>0.8,"G",IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$21,"good",$B$2:$B$21,B2)/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$21,B2)>=0.2,"R","B"))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Cool. What if I wanted to set up a range as one of my conditions. As in what if 20-80% of "goods" occuring a subject means a subject id needs further review? I'll add a sample table momentarily.

Comment: Then IF nesting should be a bit different as it is now checking if percentage is above 0.5 or below 0.5 and if non of that it assumes it as equal to 0.5. Let's say that formula COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,"good",$B$2:$B$7,B2)/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,B2) is "Result" for easier reading. IF(Result>=0.5,"Good",IF(Result>=0.2,"Average",IF(Result>=0.1,"Needs review","Bad"))). It would give Good for 50%-100%, Average for 20%-49.(9)%, Needs review for 10-19.(9) and Bad for everything else (0-%9.(9)%)

Comment: Updated formula

Comment: I would suggest to create a LAMBDA function to avoid repetition, then to invoke it several times, this will reduce the formula: `CNT, LAMBDA(A,B, status, Bval, COUNTIFS(A,status)/COUNTIFS(B, Bval))`, then you can use `CNT` with the corresponding input parameters on each time. If the input range is the same, you can remove it as input parameter